# How to use inheritance with SFML to add functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I'm working with c++ and SFML, but I have an issue with trying to inherit from their sf::Sprite abstract class. Due to the nature of my spatial partitioning, each sprite has a chance of being drawn for as many grid cells as it touches, here in the render code

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.GetGrid().size(); i++){
            for(int k = 0; k < board.GetGrid()[i].GetMovableObjects().size(); k++){
                window.draw(board.GetGrid()[i].GetMovableObjects()[k]);
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < board.GetGrid()[i].GetStationaryObjects().size(); j++){
                window.draw(board.GetGrid()[i].GetStationaryObjects()[j]);
            }
        }
```

So the loop tells each cell to draw all the objects it contains, so some objects (sf::Sprites) can be drawn more than once, which is something I don't want. The solution is to give each object a `bool drawn` so I can see if a given object has already been drawn, like so

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.GetGrid().size(); i++){
            for(int k = 0; k < board.GetGrid()[i].GetMovableObjects().size(); k++){
                if(!board.GetGrid()[i].GetMovableObjects()[k].drawn){
                        //draw
```

The problem is this: the std::vectors `movableObjects` and `stationaryObjects` are vectors of sf::Sprite objects: `std::vector<sf::Sprite> movableObjects, stationaryObjects;`
and sf::Sprite does not have a `bool drawn;` that I can use, so I have to make my own derived class

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"

class MoveableObject : sf::Sprite{
    //this is a pure virtual function, must be implemented by inheriting classes
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates &states) {};
public:
    bool drawn;
};
```

So I change my vectors to `std::vector<MovableObject> movableObjects, stationaryObjects;` so that the obejcts here act like sprites but can also return `drawn` or whatever else I want to add. Long post, so I'll get to the point: How do I deal with vectors of abstract classes? When I attempt to add items to these vectors like `moveableObjects.push_back(sprite)` (sprite is a simple sf::Sprite) I get the compiler error "no suitable user-defined conversion from "sf::Sprite" to "MoveableObject" exists"

Trying to inherit from SFML's classes so I can add my own functions is driving me mad, so what should I do about this problem?

Comment: A few things to get you on better tracks: a) learn polymorphism correctly, you apparently have some misunderstanding of the concept, b) don't inherit from `Sprite` but instead from `Drawable` if you really want to inherit from something -- composition is usually simpler and has several benefits -- look it up.

Comment: Can you at least say what is is about the concept that I don't get? And how would I use composition is such a way that I could still hold vectors of my `MoveableObject` class objects?

Comment: A `vector<MoveableObject>` *can* hold any instance of `MoveableObject`, the fact that this class inherits or use `sf::Sprite` is not relevant. That's why I think you misunderstood something.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. I went with composition like you said, I just had to add a vector of sprites in the MoveableObject class to make sure that the derived classes can have as many sprites as their animations need.